# Can one use a Wordly Tutor to fetch Nylea, God of the Hunt

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Worldly Tutor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Worldly%20Tutor) searches your library for a creature card. So could I find [Nylea, God of the Hunt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nylea%2C%20God%20of%20the%20Hunt) with it since Nylea is an Enchantment Creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Nylea is always a Creature card (among other things) in your library.

It doesn't matter that Nylea isn't just a Creature.

---

Ruling:

> The type-changing ability that can make the God not be a creature functions only on the battlefield. It's always a creature card in other zones, regardless of your devotion to its color.

If the ability was a characteristic-defining ability, it would function in all zones.

> 604.3. Some static abilities are characteristic-defining abilities. A characteristic-defining ability conveys information about an object’s characteristics that would normally be found elsewhere on that object (such as in its mana cost, type line, or power/toughness box). Characteristic-defining abilities function in all zones. They also function outside the game.

But it's not a characteristic-defining ability because it fails criteria 5.

> 604.3a A static ability is a characteristic-defining ability if it meets the following criteria: (1) It defines an object’s colors, subtypes, power, or toughness; (2) it is printed on the card it affects, it was granted to the token it affects by the effect that created the token, or it was acquired by the object it affects as the result of a copy effect or text-changing effect; (3) it does not directly affect the characteristics of any other objects; (4) it is not an ability that an object grants to itself; and (5) it does not set the values of such characteristics only if certain conditions are met.